# Prove that $\sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}F_{i}=F_{2n}$

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

I am asked:

> Let $F_{i}$ denote the $i$-th Fibonacci number.
>   Prove that $$\sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}F_{i}=F_{2n}$$

I have the base case and the inductive hypothesis, but I'm not sure what identity I need to make the jump from

$\sum^{n+1}_{i=0}\binom{n+1}{i}F_{i}=F_{2n}+F_{n+1}$ to $F_{2n+2}$, where $F_{2n+2}$ is the n+1 term.

Any tips?

Comment: How do you have $\sum^{n+1}_{i=0}\binom{n+1}{i}F_{i}=F_{2n}+F_{n+1}$? This seems wrong -- note that $F_{2n} = \sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}F_{i} \neq \sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n+1}{i}F_{i}$ (from the IH).

Comment: @ClementC., I must be very mistaken then. Would pulling the $n+1$ term out equal $\sum^{n}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}F_{i}=F_{2n}+F_{n+1}$?

Comment: No -- the issue is not in the term you add, it is in the fact that all the binomial coefficients have $n+1$, not $n$.

Comment: Are you sure about last equation in your assumption?